# How to send Data to backend (Django) from React [list, numbers, files]

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, form-data

My question refers to [How do I append a list to FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754544/how-do-i-append-a-list-to-formdata)

However I believe it was not answered well so I am creating another question and elaborating more.

I intend to send data to Django backend via axios from React. The data includes images, primary key values and list of primary key values.

I understand that FormData cannot pass integers or list of integers and JSON cannot pass a file. What is the best way to achieve both.

If I use JSON the image is not passed and I get the error

```
["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]
```

If I use FormData the ForeignKey fields holding integers or list of integers (Many To Many Field) are not passed and I get the error

```
["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]
```

***Questions***

What is the best way to send all the data to backend?

1.) Should I make changes to backend so it can parse the strings, that is achievable but does not seem elegant as the backend should be generalised for any client side application and this seems like a particular issue case?

2.) Is there any way to send data via axios partially as FormData and partially as JSON

3.) Would sending the file converted as a bas64String in JSON format along with the data fix this problem?

Which is the most efficient and elegant way of fixing this?